# Get value of object array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following json:

```
$data = '{"code":"08261",
          "currency":"EUR", 
          "packs":[ {"amount":0.05,"measure":"g","price":73.0}, 
                    {"amount":0.1,"measure":"g","price":108.0}, 
                    {"amount":0.25,"measure":"g","price":154.0}, 
                    {"amount":0.5,"measure":"g","price":296.0}, 
                    {"amount":1.0,"measure":"g","price":394.0}, 
                    {"amount":2.5,"measure":"g","price":771.0}, 
                    {"amount":5.0,"measure":"g","price":1142.0}, 
                    {"amount":10.0,"measure":"g","price":1693.0}]}';
```

I can get the value of code and currency as follows:

```
// Option 1: through the use of an array.
$jsonArray = json_decode($data,true);

$code =  $jsonArray['code'];

// Option 2: through the use of an object.
$jsonObj = json_decode($data);

$code = $jsonObj->code;
```

How can I get the price for the following packs where the:

1. amount is '1.0' and measure is 'g'
2. amount is '5.0' and measure is 'g'
3. amount is '10.0' and measure is 'g'

Comment: Hi @adam78 does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2722213/3218652

Comment: @Simeononon this is PHP, not JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert the json into nested arrays (passing `true` to the `$associative` parameter of [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), you can then use `array_filter` to filter the packs to find the values you want:

```php
$data = '{"code":"08261",
          "currency":"EUR", 
          "packs":[ {"amount":0.05,"measure":"g","price":73.0}, 
                    {"amount":0.1,"measure":"g","price":108.0}, 
                    {"amount":0.25,"measure":"g","price":154.0}, 
                    {"amount":0.5,"measure":"g","price":296.0}, 
                    {"amount":1.0,"measure":"g","price":394.0}, 
                    {"amount":2.5,"measure":"g","price":771.0}, 
                    {"amount":5.0,"measure":"g","price":1142.0}, 
                    {"amount":10.0,"measure":"g","price":1693.0}]}'; 

function get_price($data, $amount, $measure) {
    $values = array_filter($data['packs'], function ($a) use ($measure, $amount) {
        return $a['amount'] == $amount && $a['measure'] == $measure;
    });
    if (count($values)) return reset($values)['price'];
    return 0;
}

$data = json_decode($data, true);

echo get_price($data, 1.0, 'g') . PHP_EOL;
echo get_price($data, 5.0, 'g') . PHP_EOL;
echo get_price($data, 10.0, 'g') . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
394
1142
1693
```

For those stuck with versions of PHP that don't support anonymous functions, it's simpler just to use a `foreach` loop over `$data['packs']`:

```php
function get_price($data, $amount, $measure) {
    foreach ($data['packs'] as $pack) {
        if ($pack['amount'] == $amount && $pack['measure'] == $measure) {
            return $pack['price'];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. I'm stuck with php 5.2 so I've had to use global variables to pass the parameters for the call back. I'm still getting an error on the following `reset($values)['price']` in php 5.2. Do you know how to rewrite this line so that it work in php 5.2?

Comment: @adam78 you really should upgrade! PHP5 has been out of support a long time and likely has all sorts of security holes in it. In the meantime though I've edited the answer with a solution that will work on 5.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter` like this:

```php
$jsonObj = json_decode($data);
$result = array_filter(
    $jsonObj->packs,
    fn($pack) => $pack->amount === 1.0 && $pack->measure === 'g'
);
```

That uses an [arrow function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php).
If you generalize that solution, implementing a function:

```php
function filterPacks($packs, $amount, $measure) {
    return array_filter(
        $packs,
        fn($pack) => $pack->amount === $amount && $pack->measure === $measure
    );
}

$jsonObj = json_decode($data);
print_r(filterPacks($jsonObj->packs, 5.0, 'g'));
```

According to a comment, you have "to use global variables to pass the parameters for the call back" because you're "stuck with php 5.2". You can do this in PHP 5.2.0:

```php
function filterPacks($packs, $amount, $measure) {
    $filtered = array();
    foreach ($packs as $pack) {
        if ($pack->amount === $amount && $pack->measure === $measure) {
            $filtered []= $pack;
        }
    }
    return $filtered;
}

$jsonObj = json_decode($data);
print_r(filterPacks($jsonObj->packs, 10.0, 'g'));
```

Notice there are [pitfalls when comparing floating points](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/problem-in-comparing-floating-point-numbers-and-how-to-compare-them-correctly/).